# Trying to enable/disable inputs inside <div> based on checkbox list selection(s)

Tags: jquery

I have used the following code with radio button lists (generally 2 choices). This has allowed me to place another input (textbox, another radio button list, etc.) inside a `<div>` that would be hidden until a button was clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='RadioButton1']").on ( "change", function() {

            if (this.value == "Yes") {
                $('#someDisplay, #someDisplay input').show().removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $('#someDisplay, #someDisplay input').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
    });
        $("#someDisplay, #someDisplay input").hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
</script>
```

Again, the great thing about this is that the input inside the `<div>` would remain disabled if nothing was clicked, which meant that no information was passed when the form was submitted (i.e., the input was "empty" or "null" and nothing had to be saved).

Now I am trying to use this code to work with a checkbox list. Unfortunately, if you clicked all the checkboxes it would only show the last clicked checkbox `<div>` even though prior checkboxes were clicked. I tried using JQuery `toggle()`, and while it would show/hide the `<div>` corresponding to what was clicked, the problem is if you un-clicked a checkbox, the input that was inside the `<div>` would remain enabled. Sorry if I am not clear. Here is what I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[name$='Checkbox1']").on ( "change", function() {

            if (this.value == "Choice 1") {
                $('#someDisplay1, #someDisplay1 input').show().removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $('#someDisplay1, #someDisplay1 input').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }

            if (this.value == "Choice 2") {
                $('#someDisplay2, #someDisplay2 input').show().removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else {
                $('#someDisplay2, #someDisplay2 input').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
    });
        $("#someDisplay1, #someDisplay1 input").hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#someDisplay2, #someDisplay2 input").hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
</script>
```

I was thinking that it might have been the logic of the `if/else`.

And this is the checkbox input html:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Choice 1" data-val="true">
            Choice 1
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>
            <input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="Choice 2">
            Choice 2
        </label>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: To add the hidden `<div>`:
EDIT2: Accidently deleted `disabled="disabled"`

```
<div disabled="disabled" id="someDisplay1" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Display 1</label>
    <input name="TextBox1" style="display: none;" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about the HTML for the divs. Can you post the full structure of your inputs and the divs

Comment: Is your problem how to submit in the form only the visible items ?

Comment: @TimS. Edited to add the hidden `<div>`. Note that when a click occurs the `display:` turns to `block` in the first `<div>` and for the `<input>` it becomes `inline-block`.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat That is somewhat the problem. I can use `toggle()` instead, but what happens is that all the inputs corresponding to the checkbox originally clicked - but then later un-clicked - would remain enabled and submit a "false" or "default" value, which is not what I want. If it is not checked I don't want any value submitted for the corresponding `<div>` that is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like

```
$("#the_form_id").on("submit", function(e){ 
    $("input").filter(":hidden").remove()
})
```

The concept is to erase all the hidden form elements just prior to the submit of the form.  The .filter(":hidden") is a JQuery extension so we use the faster $("input") selector first then operate on the results with the filter. Hidden looks at the element itself AND its ancestors to determine if the element is hidden.

This will of course remove those hidden elements so if you were submitting by Ajax and needed to re-use the form them you could create a new form and clone the visible form elements into it.

Comment: Surprisingly, this worked to remove the unselected `<div>`'s from the form submission. Instead of using the code above with `show()` and `hide()`, I used `toggle()`. I also removed the disabling code and opted to replace it with `css({'display': 'none'});` for each of the `<div>`'s.